# i have a HABTM ASSociation In rails with student and Subject..when i Edit Subjects then Not remove Selected Subject review my code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

```
  def update
    if @student.update(student_params)

      # habtm update method 
      params[:student][:subject_ids].each do |subject_id|
        @student.subjects << Subject.find_by(id: subject_id) if subject_id.present?
      end 
      redirect_to students_path 
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code handles data coming in from a form.  I guess you have
a list of checkboxes there?  To select all the subjects?

You code goes through all the selected subjects and adds them.

It does not ever remove a subject.

Maybe as a first step you could remove all the subjects, and only add them back in if they were selected?

```
# habtm update method 
@student.subjects = []
params[:student][:subject_ids].each do |subject_id|
  @student.subjects << Subject.find_by(id: subject_id)
end
```

Comment: Yes ,If there is any query that this subject should be deleted while editing, please give it in  Update method.

Comment: When I edit a subjects I want to be able to select a new subjects if the subject I select and get deleted, and also with the same query in the update method.

Comment: thanks @bjelli your answer Is help for me.

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to know for sure what you're asking here, but is this what you're after:

```
  @student.subjects = Subject.where(id: params[:student][:subject_ids])
```

Comment: My query is that when I do edit subject the already selected subject gets destroyed and then when I start a new one the same appears.
And also to write a query of destroy in the method of upadate which is the habtm association.